# execute windows programs from cygwin terminal?

Tags: windows-7, cygwin

How can I use my cygwin terminal on Windows 7 to execute Windows programs as I would normally do using the Windows `cmd` terminal?

It seems like there are programs that only work when executed from the directory where the `.exe` file lies. I would like to be able to execute them from where the input data files are, but it seems adding them to the $PATH won't work, probably due to dir names like `/Program Files (x86)/`. Any ideas?

Comment: What problem are you facing? That normally works out of the box?!

Comment: It seems like there are programs that only work when executed from the directory where the .exe file lies.

Comment: And these work with `cmd`? Can't you just `cd` into the directory in cygwin (`cd /cygdrive/c/...`) and start the program there?